# Convert unstacked multi indexed dataframe to a single index as DateTimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that is indexed by `DateTimeIndex` at the begining of my code. Which looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
timeindex = pd.date_range('8/12/2022', '8/18/2022', freq='min')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(timeindex)), columns=['value'], index=timeindex)
print(df.head())
                        value
2022-08-12 00:00:00  1.764052
2022-08-12 00:01:00  0.400157
2022-08-12 00:02:00  0.978738
2022-08-12 00:03:00  2.240893
2022-08-12 00:04:00  1.867558
```

Then I convert it to a dataframe that is index using time (axis=0) and date as the columns (axis=1) and do some analysis afterwards. It looks like the following:

```
df = df.set_index([df.index.date, df.index.time]).unstack(level=0)
print(df.head())
             value                                                         
         2022-08-12 2022-08-13 2022-08-14 2022-08-15 2022-08-16 2022-08-17   
00:00:00   1.764052   0.147434  -0.691020   0.718456   1.198187  -0.088724   
00:01:00   0.400157  -0.977465  -2.205505   1.576193  -0.336650   1.512770   
00:02:00   0.978738   0.879390   0.447870   0.441869   0.841947   0.573708   
00:03:00   2.240893   0.635425  -0.755751  -0.816861   0.543372  -0.541004   
00:04:00   1.867558   0.542611   1.325708   0.745505  -0.962988   0.101177
```

Now, I want to convert my dataframe back to the original form as the first one. How can I do that? (I know if I read my dateframe again I will get it as the first form but I do not want to do it.)

**My try**
I use the following but I do not know how to combine date and time:

```
df.unstack()
value  2022-08-12  00:00:00    1.764052
                   00:01:00    0.400157
                   00:02:00    0.978738
                   00:03:00    2.240893
                   00:04:00    1.867558
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.index.get_level_values` to concatenate your indexes and columns into their old form

```
new_df =  df.unstack()
new_df.index = [new_df.index.get_level_values(1), new_df.index.map('{0[1]} {0[2]}'.format)]
```

However, this will not drop the level 0 multi-index, So you now have

```
2022-08-12  2022-08-12 00:00:00    1.764052
            2022-08-12 00:01:00    0.400157
            2022-08-12 00:02:00    0.978738
            2022-08-12 00:03:00    2.240893
            2022-08-12 00:04:00    1.867558
                                 ...   
2022-08-18  2022-08-18 23:55:00         NaN
            2022-08-18 23:56:00         NaN
            2022-08-18 23:57:00         NaN
            2022-08-18 23:58:00         NaN
            2022-08-18 23:59:00         NaN
```

You can drop multi-index level with `index.droplevel`

```
new_df.index = new_df.index.droplevel(0)
```

Lastly, you will see you will have `NaN` values at the end of the series as expected. These `NaN` came when you applied `df.unstack` at the beginning. You can either enter the last date if you know it, or just pass

```
new_df[new_df.index <= first_df.index[-1]]
```

Note that I intentionally called it `first_df`. `first_df` is simply the dataframe at the beginning that didn't go under any transformation

Comment: What does `'{0[1]} {0[2]}'.format` do in the argument of map function? How can you do it using `f-string`.

Comment: The last line does not work and I get the following error: `TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'Timestamp'`

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 =  df.unstack()
df2.index = df.unstack().index.droplevel(0).map(lambda x: f'{x[0]} {x[1]}')
df2 = df2.dropna()
df2

2022-08-12 00:00:00    1.764052
2022-08-12 00:01:00    0.400157
2022-08-12 00:02:00    0.978738
2022-08-12 00:03:00    2.240893
2022-08-12 00:04:00    1.867558
                         ...   
2022-08-17 23:56:00   -0.528628
2022-08-17 23:57:00   -0.561362
2022-08-17 23:58:00    0.459419
2022-08-17 23:59:00    0.461485
2022-08-18 00:00:00   -0.841556
```